# GET unified groups I’m member of is returning AD groups even with Unified filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the information from this page:

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs

Which gives the example REST call to get the Unified Groups:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')

BUT

This is still returning every group in my AD not filtering to just the Unified groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query instead:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')
```

Comment: The link is the answer - it's a REST request.  Wes's REST call had a spurious "?" after the memberOf.  This led Microsoft Graph to ignore the rest of the query parameter (because it is invalid), and return all the groups.  This is actually a bug.  We'll be fixing this, so that Wes's request would actually return an error in the future.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I cut and paste the REST call direct from http://graph.microsoft.io/docs so that content is incorrect I'll go and setup a PR for the content tonight for the correction. Thanks

Comment: @WesHackett Yes please!

Comment: If I use this request in Postman or an Angular SPA I'm getting the following error:

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported segment type.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "748c170b-5ea3-4199-9e30-cc24a8a884ab",
            "date": "2015-11-21T14:07:35"
        }
    }
}

My application has the following permissions: AllSites.Read Directory.AccessAsUser.All Group.Read.All Sites.Search.All User.Read.

Calling the memberOf endpoint in the same app/Postman works as expected.